# Init.rc : service killed and restarts

Tags: android, c, shell, init

I'm running shell script in init.rc as a service but it killed and restarts continuously.

Service registering in init.rc as follows

```
service Storelog /system/bin/logwrapper /system/bin/store_log.sh
user root
disabled
```

and script store_log.sh is

```
#!bin/sh
while true 
do
 echo "Updating system log.."
 logcat > /data/system.log &
 sleep 600 
 echo "Killing background logcat."
 logpid=$!
 echo "logpid $logpid"
 kill $logpid
 logcat -c

done
```

and I am starting this Storelog on some trigger like boot_completed

This service starts, after one loop its killed and restarted.

What I am missing here ?? some permission ?? 
Any suggestion are helpful.

Comment: why do you use `kill $logpid`?

Comment: I don't want bee run logcat background process continuously so killing that background process and starting again after sometime

Answer (score 0):

according to this page: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/logcat.html

the '-c' option causes logcat to exit

however, by then, the 'kill' has already exited logcat.

suggest modifying the script to: (following untested)

```
#!bin/sh
while true 
do
 echo "Updating system log.."
 logcat -d > /data/system.log &
 sleep 600 
done
```

Comment: I want to clear the logcat which i have already dumped and next time I want dump new logs. So I was using logcat -c . According to android developer page u mentioned also says same. Basically it will clear all the log buffer like main, system etc and kills the process as for i know.

Answer (score -2):

you can try to add oneshot tag to the service

service Storelog /system/bin/logwrapper /system/bin/store_log.sh

user root

disabled

oneshot